# API service to return computed prices and display them on front end as they complete

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, websocket, service

**Scope of Architecture:** Java Spring boot API service that utilizes a microservice which can only compute one request at a time. React frontend makes AJAX request to API.

**Question:** Let’s say I have a list of items, and I need to send an API call to a service to compute the prices for each of those items. How would you implement a service endpoint to return a computed price for x item when it completes and display it on the front end? Would a websocket be the only way?

*Computing the prices is restricted to one item at a time.*

*Each item can take between 0>n<=100 time (seconds).*

**Example:**

```
items = [1,2,3,4]
Computing for 6 seconds...
return [1=$2.00]
Computing for 12 seconds...
return [2=$3.89]
```

Comment: Is the service (that will compute) just another spring boot app?

Comment: Yes it is! Reason we need it separate is because it will attain a static IP that's whitelisted to make certain requests, whereas the API that calls this microservice has a dynamic IP that changes frequently.